# trying to set global "$ADMIN" variable to allow or deny access to the admin area of my site

Tags: php, session, admin

I am using a header file with the following code:

```
<?php
    $ADMIN = False;
   if(session_id() == '') {
   // session has NOT been started
     session_start();

   }
   else
    {
         // session has been started
      }
  ?>
```

The code I have to check the state of the admin variable is this :

```
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($account_type)){
    if($row2['account_type'] == 'A'){
        $ADMIN = 'true';}
        else{$ADMIN = 'false';}
```

and every time I try to access the page with the site on I get an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$ADMIN' (T_VARIABLE)
```

Comment: On what line number do you get the error?

Comment: Are you including the code to check the state of admin before header?

Comment: Also note that `false` and `'false'` are completely different.

Comment: You can simplify the last three lines in your second block to just this: `$ADMIN = $row2['account_type'] == 'A';`. See if this solves the error.

Comment: When you get the parse error, usually it is a good idea to post entire code, not only 2 chunks, that appear to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit to define a new solution for this...

If you need access to something everywhere, try creating an admin helper class with static state definition.

```
// Make sure to require this everywhere in your application
class Admin {
    private static $_is_admin = false;

    public static setAdminState($is_admin) {
        // Always store a boolean
        self::$_is_admin = $is_admin ? true : false;
    }

    public static isAdmin() {
        return self::$_is_admin;
    }
}

// Set your status like this
if ($row2['account_type'] == 'A') {
    Admin::setAdminState(true);
} else {
    Admin::setAdminState(false);
}
```

Then, you can access it anywhere (even in the scope of functions and classes), as follows:

```
if (Admin::isAdmin()) {
    // something
}
```

Comment: Except that you can't undefine or change a global constant.

Comment: What was wrong with constants? Why would  you need to change or unset the state?

Comment: He's setting the value in a loop.  So he would be trying to define the same constant multiple times.

Comment: Also, it's a bad habit to use constants to define dynamic application state parameters.  A constant (as its name suggests) should be immutable in your application.

Comment: would that go in the session() ? ??